# 15A circuit allowed to supply multiple general purpose receptacles?

Tags: electrical, wiring, nec

For some reason I have it in my head that there is a section in the NEC which prevents the use of anything smaller than 20A circuits to supply multiple general purpose receptacles.

While I know for certain that the use 20A circuits to supply residential multiwire circuits is common convention and a requirement for some outlets in kitchens, laundry rooms, and bathrooms (sections from 210.11 of the 2014 NEC quoted below), I cannot seem to find a section in the NEC which prohibits the use of 15A circuits to supply multiple general purpose receptacles in other areas of the house. This is not to say I plan to deviate or am advocating deviating from this convention for circuits which supply multiple receptacles, I would just like to confirm whether I somehow tricked myself into thinking it is actually required by the NEC or if it is really just a good common convention.

> ***From NFPA-70:2014 (2014 NEC)***
>
> **210.11 Branch Circuits Required.**
>
> ...
>
> **(C) Dwelling Units.**
>
> **(1) Small-Appliance Branch Circuits.** In addition to the
>   number of branch circuits required by other parts of this
>   section, two or more 20-ampere small-appliance branch circuits
>   shall be provided for all receptacle outlets specified by
>   210.52(B).
>
> **(2) Laundry Branch Circuits.** In addition to the number
>   of branch circuits required by other parts of this section, at
>   least one additional 20-ampere branch circuit shall be provided
>   to supply the laundry receptacle outlet(s) required by
>   210.52(F). This circuit shall have no other outlets.
>
> **(3) Bathroom Branch Circuits.** In addition to the number
>   of branch circuits required by other parts of this section, at
>   least one 120-volt, 20-ampere branch circuit shall be provided
>   to supply a bathroom receptacle outlet(s). Such circuits
>   shall have no other outlets.
>
> *Exception: Where the 20-ampere circuit supplies a single
>   bathroom, outlets for other equipment within the same
>   bathroom shall be permitted to be supplied in accordance
>   with 210.23(A)(1) and (A)(2).*

Comment: If you are using 15A receptacles (Mr. Horrified not Mr. Winky) on a 20A circuit, it is **mandatory** to have at least two receptacles. A duplex receptacle will suffice.

Comment: In fact, in Canada, the code prohibits having 15A receptacles on a 20A circuit: you need combo 15A/20A receptacles (aka T-slot). I supposed they figured that a 15A receptacle would not be rated to have 20A going through, despite the relatively small difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the US under the NEC in a residential setting there is no prohibition for a 15A general use receptacle circuit. You are correct in that some areas; kitchens (and similar/associated rooms), laundry, bathrooms, do require 20A receptacle circuits, but there is nothing that prohibits 15A receptacle circuits in most other places.

Comment: The only difference on a 15 & 20 amp circuit is the total # of outlets allowed. Other than the amperage.

Comment: @EdBeal, and in a dwelling setting there is no limitation on number of receptacles or outlets on a circuit.

Comment: there absolutely is a maximum number for both 15 & 20 amp circuits each outlet or yoke for duplex circuits I don't have my books at home but can find several limitations and cite the number based on breaker/wire size been doing this since the 70's and it has been the same for all those years based on the code. If you think I am wrong post as a question and be prepared to get your eyes opened!

Comment: @EdBeal, sorry, but you are wrong, and I guess have been since the 70's. Would you like the code section?

Comment: The last sentence in 220.14(I).

Comment: Keep up with uninformed information and only 1 reference I think I will be able to give at least 3 in a few days

Comment: Whatever man. I am talking about a dwelling, not a lumber mill. When you find those three code citations let me know.

Comment: Here, it's been asked already: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/63324/how-many-receptacles-can-i-place-on-a-20-ampere-120-volt-breaker

Comment: Did you find those three code citations yet? I only needed one.

Comment: This is the calculation I was referring to saying it is a guideline is like saying the 15 amp limit on 14 awg wire is a guideline.  I have had redlined plans where the inspector misread the wire size. I know this to be true in at least 2 states I have built houses as a licensed electrician.

Comment: Oh. He is saying it's a guideline FOR A RESIDENTIAL INSTALLATION, which it is. It is flat out stated that this calculation does not apply to residential receptacles or outlets. Again, last sentence in 220.14(I) ...... Also, the 15A limit on #14 is basically a guideline. It's not a hard fast rule. Have you ever wired a motor or A/C unit?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45192/discussion-between-speedy-petey-and-ed-beal).